# no match for 'operator==' when using custom classes and std::find()

Tags: c++, class, comparison

I have this class `namescores_t` which is basically a data structure containing a first/last name linked to a score. While filling a vector of `namescores_t` objects, I check to see if the object already exists like so:

```
// reading from file and inserting data...
vector<namescores_t> NS;
namescores_t ns(names, scores); // initializing namescores_t object with names & scores read from file
    if(find(NS.begin(), NS.end(), ns) == NS.end()); // if object does not exist in the list, add it
      NS.push_back(ns);
```

However, I am getting an error `no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'namescores_t' and 'const namescores_t')`. when calling `find(NS.begin(), NS.end(), ns) == NS.end()`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `namescores_t`? It looks like it doesn't provide `operator==`.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the definition of `namescores_t`. Btw, the `;` at the end of the `if` line looks misplaced. Also, shouldn't you use a `std::set` instead of a `std::vector`?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: As I said it's a custom class type of mine. I've overloaded the `operator<`, which I believe in essence uses the `==` operator from the C++ standard since `<` can be used with a combination of other logical expressions to express any of the comparison operators.

Comment: @EthanR Well, you are a wrong about that assumption. We need to see your custom class to be able to help you with it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo It appears so. I suppose that is only a feature of `std::map`.

Comment: @EthanR Some algorithms requires `operator<` and others requires `operator==`. If you don't provide the right one, they won't look for other operators to replace it with. C++20 will add `operator<=>` which will be the "universal" comparison operator.

Answer (score 1):

I was under the assumption that `std::find()` was able to use `operator<` to determine equivalency, similar to `std::map`, but this is apparently not the case. So I simply overloaded the `operator==` in order to fix the issue.

```
bool namescores_t::operator==(const namescores_t &ns) const
{
  // returns whether both the names and scores of the object are equal to one another
  return (scores.get_mean() == ns.scores.get_mean() && name == ns.name);
}
```

Comment: asnwering your own quesiton is fine, but consider that based on what is in the question alone nobody could have come up with an answer but you. I suggest to fix the question also

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I understand where you're coming from, but the people who commented revealed the issue exactly--that being that the `==` operator was not overloaded.

Comment: it was revealed in comments, but all necessary information should be in the question.

Comment: I would stop complaining if you simply add "I have implemented `operator<` and expect that to be enough so that the compiler can call an `operator==`, so I didnt not implement that" or something along that line, because then the actual problem can be understood by reading the question.

Comment: The folks commenting are experienced programmers. They can draw on that experience to make connections that most folk looking for this answer cannot. If they could, they would not be looking for this answer.

Comment: consider that there is the idea that others having the same problem as you can search and find your question and the matching answer. They will not necesarily read comments, get confused by your question (as others did already) and move on